# Angular directives to be added from the Angular component instead from the template

Tags: angular, directive, ngmodel, angular-elements

I am wondering if directives like ngModel can be added from the component, after template is initialized.

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: The sort answer is: not. Angular has no an "eval" or similar, not work in this way. Angular has an object [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) or you can add to the [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent) a component, but not allow add a "directive like ngModel" (and really, it should not be necessary)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.